# How to know UISwitch button clicked

Tags: iphone, uiswitch

I have a tale which is containing a custom view interface. Here is customeview class definition.

```
@interface CustomTableCellview : UITableViewCell {

UILabel *titleOfPost;
UILabel *userProfileName;
UIImageView* profileImage;
UILabel *countOfFave;



}

 @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *profileImage;
 @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *titleOfPost;
  @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *countOfFave;
 @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *userProfileName;
```

These all values are showing in my table. I want to call a function whenever user will click either ON/OFF button. Here is my tableview class definition.

```
 @interface VIPsScreen : UITableViewController {
 NSMutableArray* tableList;

IBOutlet CustomVIPCell *tblCell;

NSMutableArray* chengdArray;

}
```

I want to store all related "userProfileName" in array  "chengdArray" which has UISWitch values "ON". How will I resolve this problem. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
[switchCtl addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

where you're initializing instances of UISwitch and

```
-(void)action:(id)sender{

}
```

as a callback method where you should check with one was switched and take actions...

Comment: Yes I am getting function call now. But how will I know in which row it is clicked. I added it like this. cell.userName.text=[profileUserName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.userProfileImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[imageData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    
    [cell.VIPsYEsNo addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];   Can I pass parameter in function "action"?

Comment: The simplest method is using tag property of VIPsYEsNo. Let's say you can set it to row index or any other index related to your data set. In the `-(void)action:(id)sender;` the sender is actually a UISwitch that was triggered, so you can take the tag value back from it.

Comment: It is working great :). Please help how to know UISwitch button is ON or OFF detection.

Comment: There is a property in the `UISwitch` declared as: `@property(nonatomic, getter=isOn) BOOL on` so you may just write `VIPsYEsNo.on`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this **[tempSwitch isOn]**  with an if statement where tempSwitch is the name of your switchView